# How to read UTF16-BE encoded bytes with length header

Tags: python, iterable

I want to decode a series of strings of variable length which have been encoded in UTF16-BE preceded by a two-bytes long big-endian integer indicating the half the byte-length of the following string. e.g:

```
Length    String (encoded)           Length    String (encoded)               ...
\x00\x05  \x00H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o  \x00\x06  \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00! ...
```

All these strings and their length headers are concatenated in one big `bytestring`.

I have the encoded bytestring as `bytes` object in memory. I would like to have an iterable function which would yield strings until it reaches the end of the `ByteString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge improvement, but your code can be streamlined a bit.

```
def decode_strings(byte_string: ByteString) -> Generator[str]:
    with io.BytesIO(byte_string) as stream:
        while (s := stream.read(2)):
            length = int.from_bytes(s, byteorder="big")
            yield bytes.decode(stream.read(length), encoding="utf_16_be")
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that the new walrus operator would be practical here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I do it like this, but somehow I'm imagining Raymond Hettinger's ["There must be a better way!"](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=1376).

```
import io
import functools
from typing import ByteString
from typing import Iterable

# Decoders
int_BE = functools.partial(int.from_bytes, byteorder="big")
utf16_BE = functools.partial(bytes.decode, encoding="utf_16_be")

encoded_strings = b"\x00\x05\x00H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00\x06\x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00!"
header_length = 2

def decode_strings(byte_string: ByteString) -> Iterable[str]:
    stream = io.BytesIO(byte_string)
    while True:
        length = int_BE(stream.read(header_length))
        if length:
            text = utf16_BE(stream.read(length * 2))
            yield text
        else:
            break
    stream.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for text in decode_strings(encoded_strings):
        print(text)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.